# Stacked chart for budgeting example

Tags: excel, graph, charts

I have data in three columns:

```
01.1.2010    Spent           555  
01.1.2012    Planned       34343  
01.1.2012    Spent          6565  
01.1.2014    Planned       34312  
01.1.2015    Planned        2323
```

I wish to create a stacked chart where the horizontal axis will have only dates, and if there's data, stack the planned amount and spent amount in one bar.  So in this case I should have four columns and the column for 2012 date should be stacked with `Planned` first (one color) and `Spent` (different color).

How might I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be easiest to rearrange your source and then allow Excel to 'do its thing':

[image: SO18739946 example]